# Automated way to slice a panoramic photo to print as several normal photos for stitching

Tags: software, panorama

Is there any software which allows to *automatically* slice a panoramic photo so that it can be printed as several normal dimension photographs to stitch after printing?

Say I have a 9x2 image which can be printed as 3 3x2 photographs which can be stitched to produce a 9x2. I could obviously prepare the 3 images manually, but this looks like an easy task to automate. Do you know of any software which does such slicing automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the software packages for creating panoramas also have the ability to automatically tile images for the printer, so even if you don't need the panoramic creation portion, the printing portion can be used. Most of them appear to be pretty inexpensive, one of the first ones I found, [Panorama Plus](http://www.serif.com/panoramaplus/) is $29.99 US which isn't outrageuous, though it doesn't appear that they have a trial option. Anyways, a quick Google search will find you plenty of options.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I was just using a wrong search keyword. Tiling is what I should have been googling for.

Answer (score 4):

If I were doing this, I'd just use one of the several Internet services that can print big panoramas directly, with no stitching - no seams, and no hassle of assembling. If you choose a shop with good color calibration, you can be confident the results will look as you expect.

It's not for everyone, of course (some people really like to print themselves), but worth considering IMO.